# Equivalent of None in Scala

Tags: scala, python-3.x, nonetype

`None` is used to represent the absence of a value in Python.

For example, a node class for linked lists:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node
```

Is there way to do this in Scala? I tried `null` but some sources advise against its usage.

```
class Node(new_data: Integer = null, new_next_node: Node = null) {
        var data = new_data
        var next_node = new_next_node
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same in Scala but Scala is typed, so a value that might be absent has to have the type `Option[T]`

`case class Node(value: Option[Int] = None, node: Option[Node] = None)`

Answer (score 3):

In fact I also don't think use `var` is good practice in Scala. Perhaps you can define/initialize `Node` in the other way to avoid mutability.

But if you'd like to keep the code as much similar as the Python one, `null` is fine at least for `new_next_node`. And `new_data` can be initialized to some default value with type `Int` instead of using the boxed `Integer`; if `new_data` should be initialized by cases, it's better to use `value: Option[Int] = None` as @Sleiman Jneidi's answer has suggested.

Still, keep in mind that in Python, checking like `if a is None` is *pythonic*; however checking `if a.isDefined` against `Option` type is not quite *scalaistic*.